# How can I increase and decrease the height attribute when users scrolls on the +y axis and -y axis?

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

Below is the code I've written for the SVG. I'm trying to manipulate the height attribute for the ID #temp, whenever the user scrolls.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"viewBox="0 0 25.25 104" enable-background="new 0 0 25.25 104" xml:space="preserve">
  <rect  id="temp" width="10"  style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" transform="rotate(180,5,2)" x="-7" y="-100">
   <!-- <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="95" dur="3s"/> --> 
  </rect>


<path id="thermo" d="M15.8,0H9.2C4.679,0,1,3.678,1,8.199V95.8c0,4.521,3.679,8.2,8.2,8.2h6.6c4.521,0,8.23.679,8.2-8.2V8.199
C24,3.678,20.321,0,15.8,0z M22,95.8c0,3.419-2.781,6.2-6.2,6.2H9.2C5.781,102,3,99.219,3,95.8V84.5h8.25v-2H3v-6.357h8.25v-2H3
v-6.357h8.25v-2H3v-6.356h8.25v-2H3v-6.357h8.25v-2H3v-6.357h8.25v-2H3v-6.357h8.25v 2H3V26h8.25v-2H3V8.199C3,4.781,5.781,2,9.2,2
 h6.6C19.219,2,22,4.781,22,8.199V95.8z"> 
</path>
```

below you can see the JQuery I've written to get a minimum height of 5 for #temp when the page is loaded. Then I'm trying to increase the height attribute by one every time a user scrolls. This doesn't seems to be working for me. I would appreciate the help.

```
var initHeight = $("#temp").attr("height", 5);initHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function(){

$("#temp").attr("height", 5) ++;

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/strawberrybeard/6J844/23/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're setting a variable `initHeight` to what looks like a function, then calling it as a function, but it isn't a function. You need declare it like this in order to use it like a function:

```
var initHeight = function(){ $("#temp").attr("height", 5); }
```

I also declared a variable for the starting number, 5. Inside the scroll event, increment `newHeight`, then set the height to this new number.

```
var newHeight = 5;

$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    newHeight += 1;
    $("#temp").attr("height", newHeight);
});
```

You could also increment inside the `attr` call like this: `++newHeight` which increments it before setting it. Using `newHeight++` will set the height, then increment it.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6J844/26/)**

Comment: Brouxhaha! Thanks so much for looking  into this and answering my question so simply!